# Process-shared lock under FreeBSD

Tags: pthreads, freebsd, spinlock

Just like the following code snippet:

```
pthread_spin_init(&lock, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
```

Under Linux, I can use process-shared spinlock, but when I compile the same code under FreeBSD 10.3, I get EINVAL.

Is FreeBSD 10.3 **still** doesn't support PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED?

If true, is there exists any alternative solution to implement a lightweight process-shared lock?

Comment: According to the pthread_rwlock_init(3) man page, it is not supported in FreeBSD 10 stable.

Comment: So do you know any alternatives?

Comment: No, sorry. I didn't create it as answer as it didn't include a solution.

Comment: This is supported in FreeBSD 11.1. On older FreeBSDs you can use a semaphore to emulate a spin lock, but since it is a system call it will be slower.